# Close Modal Dialog Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am currently implementing a modal dialog screen into my website for the registration page, to save time for you i am not going to lie and say that i am following this tutorial - http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

It all works fine except it does not show how to close the dialog on the user clicking outside of it, like on the rest of the body around it.

How can i do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: register a click on the overlay and close the box

Comment: If using javascript libraries is an option, you'll be better off using something like [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) on top of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead of implementing it from scratch. $(document).ready(function() { $(".fancybox").fancybox(); }); It is highly configurable and thus, saves you a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call `overlay()` again from whatever event you want to trigger the close. It toggles the visibility of the overlay (if the overlay is visible, calling `overlay()` hides it and vice versa):

```
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

You may also consider using something like [jQuery UI's dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, but i put it round the div like this `<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'><div id="overlay">
   
</div></a>` But it still won't close it, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1136379: Add the click event to the overlay itself, like this: `<div id="overlay" onclick='overlay()'>`.

Comment: Great that works, the only problem is that my overlay is the transparent background, and inside that i have another div with all the modal content, but whenever i click in that (its a registration modal) it closes, is there any way i can only make it for when you click on the transparent background. Thanks